# Python 3.3: Access string internal representation?

Tags: python, string, unicode, python-3.3

In Python >= 3.3, in order to help troubleshoot Unicode encoding and decoding issues, I would like to be able to examine, from Python code, the actual internal data stored in strings. How do I do that?

There is a str.encode() method, which returns a bytes representation, but in general this is a byte sequence as translated by a particular codec (selected by the "encoding" argument), not the actual raw bytes stored in the str object.

There is a "unicode_internal" encoding option, but it's deprecated, and it's not clear whether, in 3.3, it returns the real internal data (organized how?), or some translation of it.

PEP 393 describes the internal structure of Unicode data, from which it appears that access to this from Python would need to report string kind (1/2/4 byte), representation (ASCII/compact) and also an array of bytes containing the string contents, (whose format is ASCII, UCS1, 2, or 4, I think).

I've not found methods on the str type that offer this access within Python.

Is there some other approach? Perhaps a clever way to use struct? Or a C library that exposes these string internals?

Update 2014-03-13:

Thanks to all who have responded with advice about why one should not want to access a string's internal structure. This is certainly valid advice for a normal Python program.

Nonetheless, my question is: how to do it?

To expand on the rationale: it is in order to troubleshoot encoding-decoding problems, where one function (in some library perhaps) creates and returns a str, and another function (perhaps in some other library) is supposed to do something with that str.

I want to inspect the exact contents of that intermediate str,  (ie: I want to split the problem space in half), and to do so without introducing the further variable of having one or another python function transform that data into some other form (like ASCII with escape sequences).

Amongst other reasons, I want to know the exact internal data in case one of another of the libraries is actually sensitive to the internal data format. Said libraries might well be written in C, have access to that data, and handling it incorrectly.

Also, it is indeed supposed to be the case that a str should be treatable as a sequence of code points with internal internal representation of no concern. But if there is actually a bug in string handling, I don't want to be misled by it, and if there isn't, I'd like the confidence that there isn't. Given the complexity of the string library, zero bugs would be quite an achievement.

So: How might I inspect the string's internal structure?

Comment: How would the internal representation help you troubleshoot encoding or decoding issues? I'd stick with `ascii()` when trying to determine the contents.

Comment: Unless you are writing C extensions that need to deal with the `str` type internals, there is absolutely no need to deal with the internal C structures. That's like trying to handle the internal hash table of the `dict` type; it has no bearing on encoding or decoding issues from Python code.

Comment: Either encoded or not you are looking for a _particular interpretation of bytes by an encoding_. If I don't recall wrong, I saw a while ago that Python's unicode are stored as UTF-16 internally. I'll check this. But just to mention, even Unicode needs a way to store itself in memory which ultimately translate to bytes from a specific encoding.

Comment: @PauloBu: [Python 3.3 and up will use Latin-1, UCS-2 or UCS-4](http://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.3.html#pep-393), depending on the actual contents of the string, to safe memory. However, *this is entirely transparent* to Python code, and has no bearing on what happens when you try to encode such a value to bytes.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thanks for the clarification, I'm pretty sure I saw UCS-2 (UTF-16) when checking Python2 source.

Comment: @PauloBu: that is why the OP is talking about Python 3.3 and up. Python 2, as well as 3.0-3.2 uses UCS-2 or UCS-4, depending on a compile-time switch.

Comment: @PauloBu: UCS-2 and UTF-16 are different encodings.  The confusion between those to has caused a lot of pain for programmers already.

Comment: @SvenMarnach I can understand they are two different things but this is from Unicode's FAQ: _UCS-2 does not define a distinct data format, because UTF-16 and UCS-2 are identical for purposes of data exchange. Both are 16-bit, and have exactly the same code unit representation._ http://www.unicode.org/faq/basic_q.html#14

Comment: @PauloBu: UCS-2 is a fixed-length format that can't encode all Unicode characters.  If you encode something as UTF-16 and then decode as UCS-2, you'll end up with surrogate pairs still in the string, which is most likely not what you want.  Strings in encoded in UCS-2 are valid UTF-16, so you have compatibility in that direction.

Comment: To reiterate: Unicode string in Python is a sequence of Unicode codepoints. The way it is stored in memory has no effect on encoding and decoding issues. There were some corner cases in the past that exposed the internal representation. Unless there is a bug in Python  3.3+ or there are time performance or memory issues; you shouldn't care how Python stores the strings internally.

Comment: @Paulo Bu and later readers: UCS2 uses 16-bit values to encode only the subset of Unicode-representable characters having code pt <= 0xFFFF. UCS2 strings have a count of values = count of chars. UTF-16 also 16-bit values, with same vals as UCS2 up to 0xFFFF, but UTF-16 uses a sequence of two vals for code points > 0xFFFF. Hence, in UTF-16, the count of _values_ may be greater than the count of _chars_, and the position of a particular char within the sequence of vals cannot be calculated without reading the values up to that char (ie: array index into a string would be slow).

Comment: @ Paulo Bu and later readers: And to be even clearer, Paulo made a reasonable conclusion from the FAQ statement that he quoted, but it appears to be incorrect, or refers to UTF-16 not including code points outside UCS-2's range, or prior to some date, etc. FWIW, I filed an issue report at unicode.org.

Comment: @PaoloBu: The UCS-2 vs UTF-16 FAQ item on unicode.org has now been updated and moved to: http://www.unicode.org/faq/utf_bom.html#utf16-11, which is clearer that they are different, but still vaguely worded as to exactly how. Sigh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python's internal string representation is strictly an internal implementation detail and might well vary from one version of Python to the next and upon the operating system. Since the question specifies Python version number >=3.3, I'll assume that we're talking about CPython (1/2/4 byte character representation) and use the CPython implementation detail that id() gives the memory address. The following uses Ubuntu 19.10's system CPython 3.7.5.

```
from ctypes import string_at
from sys import getsizeof
from binascii import hexlify
a = "ABCDE"
print(hexlify(string_at(id(a), getsizeof(a))))
```

Outputs:

```
b'0100000000000000c0988500000000000500000000000000625866dab454b033e
  50064016c006d010000000000000000414243444500'
```

You can see the "ABCDE" at the end of the hex, counting up from 41 to 45. If a chracter is added to that string from the Unicode codepoint range 128-255 such as the cent sign at 0xA2, "¢ABCDE", that character can still be represented in a single byte, so that's what CPython does, although the row of nulls in front of the string grows for some reason:

```
b'0200000000000000c09885000000000006000000000000003b7ac7a960368ad4a
  4005a006501650200000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
  00000000000000a2414243444500'
```

If a character above Unicode 255 is added to the string instead, such as the oe-ligature at 0x153, "œABCDE", then the whole string switches to two bytes per character, with "œ" being the little-endian "5301", "A" being "4100" and so on:

```
b'0200000000000000c0988500000000000600000000000000e50dd134c7e9b87ca
  83d22c59341424300000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
  000000000000005301410042004300440045000000'
```

Comment: That's pretty much what I was looking for, oh those many years ago. I hope I get a chance to revisit this topic at some point.

Comment: Cool. Better late than never. The usual curse of Googling for obscure issues is that the first hit is a Stackoverflow question with no answer. If I do happen to stumble upon the answer later then I do like to go back and answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

A Unicode string in Python should be considered as a sequence of Unicode code points.  How this is represented internally is completely immaterial to encoding and decoding issues.

You can access the numerical values of the Unicode code points by using the `ord()` function on the individual characters of the string:

```
>>> list(map(ord, "abc €"))
[97, 98, 99, 32, 8364]
```

I don't think this is particular helpful for debugging encoding issues (or for anything else), but it might clarify what a Unicode string is conceptually.

Comment: Yes, I am well aware that the Python 3.3+ model of string is that it is a sequence of code points, with internal representation intended to be of no concern to Python code (though, of course, it may still be a concern in terms of space consumption, copy speed, and so on).  I have added to my question statement the rationale for wanting nonetheless to inspect the internal structure's data -- conceptually, to check that this "no concern" is fulfilled, both by the Python libraries, and other libraries that handle strings.

Answer (score 0):

The internal switch to a more space-efficient storage for unicode values [introduced by PEP-393](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0393/) were made for **performance reasons** only.

As such they have zero impact on how encoding from and decoding to unicode `str` values works in Python code. There is absolutely *no point* in accessing the internal representation from Python. The character `A` is either stored as `41`, `4100` or `41000000`, depending on how much space the highest codepoint in the string demands, but it'll still be encoded to `41` in ASCII, Latin-1 or UTF-8.

Unless you are writing a C extension that has to deal with this internal representation, there is absolutely no need to worry about how Python actually stored the data.

To debug encoding or decoding issues, I'd use the [`ascii()` function](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#ascii) to represent a string using only ASCII codepoints and Python string literal escapes, or you can use the [`ord()` function](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#ord) for turning individual characters into an integer for each codepoint.

For bytes values, the [`binascii.hexlify()` function](http://docs.python.org/3/library/binascii.html#binascii.hexlify) also comes in handy to quickly turn a series of bytes into their hex representations.

Comment: Thanks Martijn for your response pertaining to normal Python programs. I have added to my question the rationale for why I do actually want to inspect the internal representation of a string. The suggestions regarding ascii and ord are useful for problems in this neighborhood, but don't transparently reveal the internal structure actually used for a particular string. Ie: One is still dependent on an additional library function to transform the string internal rep to ASCII, from which one might infer what rep was used.

Comment: For your hypothetical situation, you'd test it with building strings that according to the PEP would result in different internal structures and test with those to see if the 3rd party library behaviour changes. **This is an extreme edgecase however**, and in my opinion, a straw man. There is no access to the internals from Python because such edgecases are entirely in the realm of C and you'd use C debuggers to deal with that. You can then study the Python source code and API documentation if you want to deal with that situation.

Comment: If this class of problems is uninteresting to you, that's fine, but that doesn't mean it's uninteresting to others, or that it's universally a straw man. I concur that one could investigate using test cases, a C debugger etc. That said, if there is a rationale for investigating using a C debugger, then why would one be uninterested in methods to investigate them directly from Python?  The point of my question is to find out if indeed there is such a way. It sounds like you've not needed one, and don't imagine needing one -- OK fair enough.

Comment: No, I am telling you why there is no such access from Python to the internals. It's not that I am not interested, but **there is no such API in Python** to see that internal representation.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  In line with shielding Python code from string internals, I did expect that there would be no direct API to the internal representation provided out-of-the-box (or that it would be a relatively obtuse byte-inspecting API). That led to the suggestion in my question that there might exist a C library that somebody had cooked up to facilitate such inspection.